# Selenium4 webdriver Python не могу найти элемент

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Я хочу найти элемент по классу что бы кликал вод так:
klin = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, '.positive ')
klin.click()
Получаю такую ошибку:
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified Перепробывал все гайды нечего не помогает.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пробел это разделитель между классами, а не часть имени класса.

Comment: А как обращаться правильно не подскажеш?

Comment: Без пробела же. `(By.CLASS_NAME, '.positive') `. Более того, может и точка в имени класса не нужна (я точно не знаю, я не использую такой тип селекторов), это же не css-селектор